# Is is possible to search gmail via imap for multiple X-GM-THRIDs in one request?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I have many X-GM-THRIDs for which I want to retreive the list of uids for those threads.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions describes how to find these for a single X-GM-THRID. However, it would be nice if I could make one request for all of the X-GM-THRIDs that I want the data for. When I try this, I only get error codes.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm using python and doing something like:

```
res, ids = imap_conn.uid('search', 'X-GM-THRID', thread_id)
# this works fine.
```

But I'd like to do something like:

```
res, ids = imap_conn.uid('search', 'X-GM-THRID', [thread_id1, thread_id2])
```

---

UPDATE:

after @max's answer, I'm now doing something like this:

```
res, ids = imap_conn.uid(
    'search', None, 
    '(OR (OR (X-GM-THRID 123) X-GM-THRID 456) X-GM-THRID 789)')
# 123, 456, 789 are fake gmail thread ids
```

I'm not sure exactly what or how gmail limits search length - I think it's probably number of characters rather than number of 'OR's in the query. I can get away with about 9 before gmail starts returning errors.

Comment: If I have more than 10 messages in one thread, How would I will be able to produce results, I using my code You can retrieve as much as UIDs present in Thread_ID. 10 or more than 10

Comment: The code above retrieves all the message ids for three given threads (it makes no difference how many messages are in a thread). When I need to retrieve for example the ids for 20 threads, I would make 3 queries as above (2*9 thread ids, 1*2 thread ids), then one `fetch` command to get the messages from the ids returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add "or" qualifiers and then build an extended search query. See RFC 3501 for search format.

Comment: This solution works, thanks. However, it seems that Gmail has recently imposed a limit of 10 on the number of "OR"s you can use in a query, which kind of sucks :(

Answer (score -1):

I am able to get UIDs from thread-ID using following set of code.

```
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

mail = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')


mail.login(<Email>,<password>)

mail.select('INBOX')

result, uid = mail.uid('search',None,"ALL") # Get all the UIDs

uid_list = []

for uids in uid[0].split():
    uid_list.append(uids)

    for p in uids_list:

        result, data = mail.uid('fetch', p, '(X-GM-THRID)')    

        q = data[0].split() #splitting all thread IDs into list.

        m = q[2]    

        res, ids = mail.uid('search', 'X-GM-THRID', m)

        w = ids[0].split()

        print w  # printing UIDs related to Thread-IDs
```

At first I am getting all UIDs from Inbox and using those UIDs I am searching Thread-IDs and using those Thread-IDs I am again getting UIDs related to particular Thread-IDs.

Comment: This is extremely slow, if you want them all just do a fetch for "1:*", and fetch both uid and x-gm-thrid. This gets you pairs of uids and thread id's, all in one request, rather than n requests.

Comment: Yeah, sorry this code probably works, but I was specifically looking for a way to retrieve more than one at a time to avoid multiple requests.

Comment: @max and  lee  If you could give example with "code- snippet" things will be easier for me to understand+help new comers to solve issue+increase the quality of question+answer.

Comment: @arshpreet, updated my question with how I'm currently writing my IMAP queries to solve the question.

Comment: I think more than 10 messages can be fetched from one thread, but I will update my answer after making a runnable code. They are doing it, http://goo.gl/pRIRzu